# Pass json array from databricks to ADF as parameter/variable

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-data-factory, databricks

I am trying to pass dataframe as json from Databricks to Azure Data Factory. I use

```
for column in df.schema:
    df = df.withColumn(column.name, col(column.name).cast("string"))

df = df.fillna('')

json_df = df.select(to_json(struct(*df.columns)).alias("json"))
json_array = [row["json"] for row in json_df.collect()]

decoded_list = [json.loads(row_str) for row_str in json_array]
dbutils.notebook.exit(json.dumps(decoded_list))
```

and my problem in ADF is that -> I set first variable("to send") with output from that notebook as array then I generate for each. The problem is either my code sends it as dictionary and it expects string value (when I change variable data type to array) or when it fail before variable saying that is expected string but I've gave it array (when variable stays as a string). However, when I send a string and loop for each I got backslashes which WebActivity reads as incorrect JSON format. How to convert it properly that:

**it sends a string/array without backslashes in json format?**

[image: 2023-10-02 10:00:00]

**My solution**
I've adjusted my notebook a little bit, got rid of

```
decoded_list = [json.loads(row_str) for row_str in json_array]
```

and provided brackets as well as replace backslashes with doublequotes in notebook due to API endpoint requirements
instead

```
wrapped_json_array = ['[' + s.replace('\\"', '"') +']' for s in json_array]
```

with `wrapped_json_array` on dbutils exit

Comment: add your pipeline screenshot. where you are setting the notebook output?

Comment: @JayashankarGS done

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: My problem is that I got backslashes instead of double quotes and it casuses an JSON formatting error. I try right now with @replace(activity()) but effortlessly

Comment: How you are setting the variable. is it `@activity('Notebook1').output.runOutput` or
`@activity('Notebook1').output`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exit value from notebook is fine.
The problem is you need to set the variable correctly.
Below is the configuration in `Set Variable` activity.

`@activity('Notebook1').output.runOutput`

[image]

Then used `For Each activity` to make web request.

`Web` activity configuration.

[image]

And it successfully executed.

Notebook activity output:

[image]

Next `Set variable` activity output:

[image]

```
{
    "name": "send",
    "value": [
        {
            "metadata#uniqueid": "1",
            "metadata#FTA": "true"
        },
        {
            "metadata#uniqueid": "2",
            "metadata#FTA": "false"
        }
    ]
}
```

This value sent to for each and made web request.

[image]

Make `Set Varaible` activity of type `Array` and add above mentioned notebook activity output, don't send any strings because
`json.dumps` on that strings gives you slash.
Keep notebook exit value same `dbutils.notebook.exit(json.dumps(decoded_list))`

Comment: Thank you for elaborate reply, although you're missing one piece in your pipeline - I have this generate message because depending on source system it either creates xml or json and I need that piece. Anyway I've tried your approach with only one source system and I failed, I think my json missed brackets `[]` around the body. It didn't pass to the output in WebActivity. Maybe it needs to be for that API endpoint in order to be sent? You don't have it yet you succeed

Comment: Yeah it also depends on API endpoint. For me it only accepts json data directly without any brackets. . I didn't get source system creates xml Or json.

Comment: No problem, your answer may be helpful for others, I'll accept it as correct answer and point mine solution in edit in main post